OOM error while fine tuning
OOM error occurs even though I'm using quantization and gradient checkpointing , while fine tuning
This is my multi gpu fine tuning notebook.
It gives of memory error after 5 steps of training , I've tried many things still can figure out.
Pls help
Link :- https://www.kaggle.com/code/shaswatsingh69420/ddp-sft-trainer
